# Как заставить Popup в Kivy появляться в определенной позиции экрана?

Tags: python, popup, kivy

Задача - как заставить popup KIVY выскакивать в строго определенном месте экрана, чтобы он закрывал собой указанный widget? Установка pos: в kv-файле ничего не дает.

Answer (score 0):

Элементарно:

```
 modal = ModalView(
      size_hint=(None, None),
      pos_hint={'x': 5.0 / Window.width, 'y': 5.0 / Window.height},
      size=(dp(120), dp(50))
)
```

Окно размером 120х50 в нижнем левом углу экрана.

Вообще в Kivy, как в Linux, возможно все. Нужно только знать, как :) Конкретно по Kivy на русском языке вам быстрее всего ответят здесь - https://vk.com/kivy_ru

Comment: То есть Вы хотите сказать, что положение Popup'a управляется только через pos_hint? Это довольно странно...

Comment: Даже не знаю, что вам ответить на такой глупый комментарий... Я вам показал, КАК это работает! Дальше разбирайтесь сами.

Comment: Или по-вашему pos_hint (то есть, подсказка позиции) это 'довольно странно'? :D

Comment: Странно, что не через просто pos:. Дело в том, что требуется выводить popup точно над местом кликнутого виджета. Пересчет этого в pos_hint - кажется, довольно громоздкое дело

Comment: Поэксперемнтируйте со свойствами. Если не получится, создайте свое окно и уже выводите его, где вам нужно. Но, по-моему, это еще более громоздкое занятие.